# Calculating sums conditionally on data values

Tags: loops, if-statement, sum, stata

I have quite a large conflict dataset (71 million observations) with many variables and date (daily).

This is from the GDELT project. For each day, there is a target country and a source country of aggression. For example, on `1 January 2000`, many countries were engaged in aggressive behaviour against others or themselves.

It looks like this:

```
clear

input long date_01 str18 source_01 str19 target_01 str4 cameocode_01
20000101 "AFG"    "AFGGOV" "2" 
20000101 "AFG"    "AFGGOV" "8"
20000101 "AFG"    "ARE"    "3" 
20000101 "AFG"    "CVL"    "4" 
20000101 "AFG"    "GOV"    "10" 
20000101 "AFG"    "GOV"    "4" 
20000101 "AFGGOV" "kasUAF" "3"
20000101 "FRA"    "kasUAF" "8" 
20000101 "AFG"    "IGOUNO" "3" 
20000101 "AFG"    "IND"    "4" 
20000101 "AFG"    "IND"    "12"
20000102 "AFG"    "IND"    "19"  
end
```

Variable `date_01` is the day, `source_01` is the country that initiated aggression, `target_01` is the victim, and `cameocode_01` is the variable of concern which states the degree of hostility or cooperation. If the number is between `10` and `20`, that is a hostility event, with `20` being the more hostile. If the number is between `0` and `9`, that indicates cooperation (good event), with `9` being the friendliest.

I have managed [with help from this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934849/creating-variable-out-of-conditional-values-in-another-one) to isolate the event per country, namely to isolate the cameo codes involving a certain amount of countries (I am interested in `30`) to follow their conflict evolution through time.

I did the following:

```
foreach c in AFG IND ARE {
    generate ind_`c' = cameocode_01 if strmatch(source_01, "`c'") |  ///
                                       strmatch(target_01, "`c'")
}
```

This yields what is desired:

```
        date      source      target    cameocode   ind_AFG   ind_IND   ind_ARE

1.  20000101         AFG      AFGGOV            2         2                    
2.  20000101         AFG         IND            4         4         4           
3.  20000101         AFG      AFGGOV            8         8                     
4.  20000101         AFG         ARE            3         3        36       
5.  20000101         AFG         CVL            4         4                     
6.  20000101         AFG         GOV           10        10                      
7.  20000101         AFG         GOV            4         4                      
8.  20000101      AFGGOV      kasUAF            3                               
9.  20000101      AFGGOV      kasUAF            8                                
10. 20000101        AFG         IRQ            12        12                     
11. 20000102        AFG         IND            19        19        19
```

Whenever a given country is involved as either recipient or initiator, I create a new variable isolating that specific event and its intensity for a given date.

What I want to do now is to be able to create a standardized measure or ratio where for each date, the *sum* of conflict measures (numbers from `10` to `20`) are divided to by the *sum* of the cooperation measures (numbers from `1` to `9`) for each country.

So my desired output for this table above for `AFG 20000101` (5th column) would be:

```
(12+19) / (2+4+8+3+4+4)
```

I would like to repeat this for each date for each of the variables `ind_COUNTRY CODE` to have one number per day per country.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This was interesting but could have been a lot shorter in explaining what you seek.

Comment: Those dates may serve you fine, but for many Stata purposes they are unsuitable.  `generate betterdate = daily(string(date, "%8.0f"), "YMD")` followed by a `format' command will get you better dates.

Comment: Note that although we love to help we also expect to see a code attempt from your part to solve the problem.

Comment: I understand, but as a beginner it is sometimes frustrating. I have learned a lot from you and for that I thank you and appreciate your help.  Hopefully as I get better I will require less assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the key trick you seek.

```
clear
input long date str6 source float cameocode
20000101 "AFG"     2
20000101 "AFG"     4
20000101 "AFG"     8
20000101 "AFG"     3
20000101 "AFG"     4
20000101 "AFG"    10
20000101 "AFG"     4
20000101 "AFGGOV"  3
20000101 "AFGGOV"  8
20000101 "AFG"    12
end

egen num = total(cond(cameocode >= 10, cameocode, .)), by(date source)

egen den = total(cond(cameocode < 10, cameocode, .)), by(date source)

generate wanted = num / den

sort date source

list, sepby(source)

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     |     date   source   target   cameoc~e   num   den   wanted |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 20000101      AFG      IND          4    22    25      .88 |
  2. | 20000101      AFG      GOV          4    22    25      .88 |
  3. | 20000101      AFG   AFGGOV          2    22    25      .88 |
  4. | 20000101      AFG   AFGGOV          8    22    25      .88 |
  5. | 20000101      AFG      IRQ         12    22    25      .88 |
  6. | 20000101      AFG      GOV         10    22    25      .88 |
  7. | 20000101      AFG      CVL          4    22    25      .88 |
  8. | 20000101      AFG      ARE          3    22    25      .88 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  9. | 20000101   AFGGOV   kasUAF          8     0    11        0 |
 10. | 20000101   AFGGOV   kasUAF          3     0    11        0 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See [sections 9 and 10 in this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055) for technique. The essential idea is that many `egen` functions allow expressions as arguments, which can be more complicated than just variable names. Here we use `cond()` to specify that only values in certain intervals should be totalled.

A less transparent but less wasteful recipe in terms of creation of variables would run something like

`egen wanted =` !code for numerator!

`egen den =` !code for denominator!

`replace wanted = wanted / den`

`drop den`

Comment: I don't mind. I am just explaining a trick you may find helpful. But I see no point in repeating the same information in many separate variables. Whatever you want is already in `date         source       target        cameocode`: I can't easily imagine a Stata purpose for you which you _need_ to copy that into (hundreds of?) other variables.

Comment: Is because I will need them by country to regress them on stock returns of each specific country and I though that way would be an easy way to have it already split. But thanks for the trick, I will further look into it.

Comment: Same comment: you don't need to repeat the information to do that.